# Using Custom SenderID for outbound SMS Nexmo

Tags: c#, asp.net, vonage

Do I need to add more applicationsetting.json or code if I want to use a custom SenderID ?

assuming I have purchased the SenderID

here is my code :

```
string PhoneNo = "081375840392";
string SenderID = "CUSTOM";
var results = SMS.Send(new SMS.SMSRequest
{
       from = SenderID,
       to = PhoneNo,
       text = "Test Sms"
});
```

and here is my appsettings.json

```
{
  "appSettings": {
    "Nexmo.UserAgent": "myApp/1.0",
    "Nexmo.Url.Rest": "https://rest.nexmo.com",
    "Nexmo.Url.Api": "https://api.nexmo.com",
    "Nexmo.api_key": "369b4188",
    "Nexmo.api_secret": "0d1479g48e641c89",

    "Nexmo.Application.Id": "ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff",
    "Nexmo.Application.Key": "c:\\path\\to\\your\\application\\private.key"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no need to add more appsettings.json
Just change the from parameter

Comment: What do you mean by "Just change the from parameter"?

Comment: Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) 
I same facing this error